# Why we use <ul> <li> tags for creating menus, navbars?

Tags: html

Why we use these tags? Is it okay if I'll create a navbar with only links and divs? 
cause I need to do menu with structure like this

[image: https://imgur.com/7AdaNqh]

Isn't it gonna be too much nested, if I use `<ul>` for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "why"?

Comment: You should only be nesting 1 layer deep, which I wouldn't say is "too much"

Comment: It's mainly about creating semantically accessible markup: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H48.html

Comment: Is there some important reason? like accessibility

Comment: @metaDesign it's not only one layer deep

Comment: there is no need to use <ul> not even accesibility. But it would make sense to use <nav> for reasons of accessibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use list markup for menus and navigation bars because it is the most appropriate markup from a "semantic" point of view. The links in a menu or navigation bar constitute a list of similar items. As the [HTML 5.2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) says,

> The ul element represents a list of items, where the order of the items is not important — that is, where changing the order would not materially change the meaning of the document.

A navigation bar or navigation menu is a list of links; other types of menus may be lists of functions in an application. Early version of HTML, e.g. [HTML 3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/#menu) even had a `menu` element:

> They [i.e. the `DIR` and `MENU` elements] are intended for unordered lists similar to `UL` elements. User agents are recommended to render `DIR` elements as multicolumn directory lists, and `MENU` elements as single column menu lists. In practice, Mosaic and most other user agents have ignored this advice and instead render `DIR` and `MENU` in an identical way to `UL` elements.

`dir` and `menu` were deprecated in [HTML 4.01](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#edef-MENU); the HTML 4.01 spec says:

> We strongly recommend using `UL` instead of these elements.

In addition to browser support, there is another reason for using `ul` instead of a non-list element: **accessibility**. When a screen reader encounters an `ul`, it can **announce the number of items in the list** to the user. This is very useful, because it allows the user to decide whether they want to read the entire list or skip it. Announcing the length of a list is not possible when the list markup is replaced with a series of paragraphs or divs.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a semantic markup language. It is designed to describe *what* things are.

A menu is a list of links. Therefore we use list markup with links inside it to describe it.

Nothing stops you using list markup to describe the structure in your image:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Item 1
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem it</li>
<!-- etc -->
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ingridbelan/z28tgenp/2/
Isn't it too nested? or I should make nested items with divs?

Comment: No, it is not too nested. If you used divs, it would be just as nested, but it wouldn't tell user agents that the list was a list.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you want to create a menu, navbar, you're grouping information about your website [your links] into one place. that's where you can use lists, `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Also, it does not matter how it looks [visually], but the meaning, or the semantics, is more important here.